# How can I find the minimum value for $F(x,y,z,w)=x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+xy+zw-xz-yw-yz$

Tags: inequality, optimization

Let $x,y,z,w$ be integer numbers,and $xw=yz+1$

Find this minimum of the value
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+xy+zw-xz-yw-yz$$
This is how did it and I would like to know if I made a mistake

Let $$F(x,y,z,w)=x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+xy+zw-xz-yw-yz$$
we have that
$$2F(x,y,z,w)=(x-z)^2+(y-w)^2+(x+y)^2+(w+z)^2-2yz$$

Comment: Did you used Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Oh, sorry I did not see the extra condition that $xw = yz+1$. Yes then Michaels proposition with Lagrange multipliers could be better than my answer.

Comment: Michael Galuza, I am not sure if Lagrange multipliers would work, since the requirement is for integers.

Comment: Note that (using the additional constraint) you also have $2F(x,y,z,w) = (x+y-z-w)^2+x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+2yz+2$, which together with your result gives you a sum-of-squares representation. In particular, $0$ is a lower bound.

Comment: Why is there no $xw$ term? where did you get this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With $F$ as defined in your question, we have
$$2\,F(x,y,z,w)=(x+y-z)^2+(z+w)^2+x^2+(y-w)^2\,.$$
Clearly,  this means $F(x,y,z,w)\geq 0$.  The equality holds iff $x=y=z=w=0$, but this violates the assumption that $xw=yz+1$.  Therefore, $F(x,y,z,w)\geq 1$.

If $F(x,y,z,w)=1$, then three out of $x+y-z$, $z+w$, $x$, and $y-w$ must be $0$.  If $y-w\neq 0$, then $x+y-z=0$, $z+w=0$, $x=0$, and $xw=yz+1$.  Hence, $y-z=0$ and $yz+1=0$, a contradiction.  That is, $y-w=0$.  Consequently, $xw=yz+1$ implies $w(x-z)=1$.  Without loss of generality, we may assume that $w=1$ (otherwise, replace $(x,y,z,w)$ by $(-x,-y,-z,-w)$), so $x-z=1$ and $y=1$.  Hence, $x+y-z=2$, so $2\,F(x,y,z,w)\geq (x+y-z)^2=4$, a contradiction.

We have proven that $F(x,y,z,w)\geq 2$.  Indeed, $F(1,0,0,1)=2$.  Hence, $2$ is the minimum possible value of $F(x,y,z,w)$ for $x,y,z,w\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $xw=yz+1$.  (In fact, the minimum value is achieved if and only if $(x,y,z,w)$ is $\pm(1,0,0,1)$, $\pm(0,1,-1,1)$, or $\pm(1,-1,1,0)$.)

EDIT:  Apparently, if $x,y,z,w$ can be any real numbers such that $xw=yz+1$, it still holds that $F(x,y,z,w)\geq 2$ (where the equality cases are huge).  I only checked with Mathematica, but didn't try to prove it myself.  Hence, Michael Galuza's suggestion is a good one after all.

---

**Solution with Lagrange Multipliers**

Let $\Lambda(X,Y,Z,W,T):=F(X,Y,Z,W)+T(YZ+1-XW)$ for all $X,Y,Z,W,T\in\mathbb{R}$ be the Lagrange function for this problem.  Suppose that $(X,Y,Z,W)=(x,y,z,w)$ minimizes $F(X,Y,Z,W)=X^2+Y^2+Z^2+W^2+XY+ZW-XZ-YW-YZ$ subject to $YZ+1-XW=0$.  As discussed before, $F$ is bounded below by $0$, and the positive-definite quadratic nature of $F$ guarantees that $(x,y,z,w)$ exists.  The derivative of $\Lambda(X,Y,Z,W,T)$ with respect to each of the variables must vanish at $(X,Y,Z,W,T)=(x,y,z,w,t)$, for some $t\in\mathbb{R}$.  We have five equations:

(1) $2x+y-z-tw=0$,

(2) $2y+x-w-z+tz=0$,

(3) $2z+w-x-y+ty=0$,

(4) $2w+z-y-tx=0$, and

(5) $xw=yz+1$.

Adding Equations (1) and (4), we get $(x+w)(2-t)=0$, whence either $x+w=0$ or $t=2$.  Adding Equations (2) and (3), we get $(y+z)(1+t)=0$, whence either $y+z=0$ or $t=-1$.  Let us first assume that $y+z\neq 0$, which implies $t=-1$ and so $x+w=0$.  Therefore, Equation (1) becomes $x+y-z=2x+y-z-(-1)(-x)=0$, or $y+(-z)=-x$.  From Equation (5), we have $yz+1=xw=-x^2$, or $y(-z)=1+x^2$.  Consequently, $y$ and $-z$ are roots of the polynomial $\kappa^2+x\kappa+\left(1+x^2\right)$, but the roots of this polynomial are $\kappa=\frac{-x\pm\sqrt{-4-3x^2}}{2}$, which are not real.  Hence, the assumption $y+z\neq 0$ is false.

Now, $y+z=0$.  If $x+w=0$, then $-x^2=xw=yz+1=-y^2+1$, whence $x\neq 0$ or $y\neq 0$.  Furthermore, Equations (1) and (2) become $(2+t)x+2y=0$ and $2x+(3-t)y=0$, respectively.  For this system of linear equations in $x$ and $y$ to have a solution $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, $(2+t)\cdot(3-t)-2\cdot 2=0$, whence $t=-1$ or $t=2$.  If $t=-1$, we have $-x^2=-y^2+1$ and $x+2y=0$, but then $4y^2=(-2y)^2=x^2=y^2-1$, yielding $3y^2=-1$, which means $y\notin\mathbb{R}$.  That is, $t=2$.  If $x+w\neq 0$, then $t=2$.  Hence, regardless of the value of $x+w$, we must have $t=2$.

Now, suppose that $y+z=0$ and $t=2$.  Equation (1) means $x+(-w)=x-w=-\left(\frac{y-z}{2}\right)=-y$.  Equation (5) means $x(-w)=-xw=-1-yz=y^2-1$.  Thus, $x$ and $-w$ are roots of the quadratic polynomial $\kappa^2+y\kappa+\left(y^2-1\right)=0$, whose roots are $\kappa=\frac{-y\pm\sqrt{4-3y^2}}{2}$.  That is, the extremal points of the Lagrange function $\Lambda(X,Y,Z,W,T)$ are $(X,Y,Z,W,T)=\left(\frac{+\sqrt{4-3y^2}-y}{2},y,-y,\frac{+\sqrt{4-3y^2}+y}{2},2\right)$ or $(X,Y,W,Q,T)=\left(\frac{-\sqrt{4-3y^2}-y},y,-y,\frac{-\sqrt{4-3y^2}+y}{2},2\right)$, where $y\in\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right]$.  Hence, $F(X,Y,Z,W)$, subject to $XW=YZ+1$, is optimized at $$(X,Y,Z,W)=\left(\frac{+\sqrt{4-3y^2}-y}{2},y,-y,\frac{+\sqrt{4-3y^2}+y}{2}\right)$$ or $$(X,Y,Z,W)=\left(\frac{-\sqrt{4-3y^2}-y}{2},y,-y,\frac{-\sqrt{4-3y^2}+y}{2}\right)\,,$$ where $y\in\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right]$.  The value of $F$ at each of these optimizing points is $2$; hence, they must minimize $F$. The only integer coordinates are $\pm(1,0,0,1)$, $\pm(0,1,-1,1)$, and $\pm(1,-1,1,0)$, which correspond to $y\in\{-1,0,+1\}$.

Comment: I think you want $(y-w)^2$ instead of $y^2+w^2$ (otherwise you are missing the $yw$ term)

Comment: there is something peculiar about the original question having no $xw$ term in $F.$ Suggests possible incorrect transcription of some source, and it would be nice to know the source.

Comment: if we switch to $F - xw,$ the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix become $1,1,1,5.$

Comment: alright, choice is root lattice $D_4$ as given, mine is $A_4.$

Answer (score 1):

let $z=-v ,xw=1-yv,f=x^2+y^2+v^2+w^2+xy-vw+xv-yw+yv=(x-w)^2+2xw+(x-w)(y+v)+(y+v)^2-yv=(x-w)^2+(x-w)(y+v)+(y+v)^2+2-3yv, \\ yv \le \dfrac{(y+v)^2}{4} \implies -3yv \ge -\dfrac{3(y+v)^2}{4} \implies f \ge (x-w)^2+(x-w)(y+v)+\dfrac{(y+v)^2}{4}+2=(x-w+\dfrac{y+v}{2})^2+2 \ge 2 $

when $y=v ,x-w+y=0 \cap xw=1-y^2 ,f $ get min

now we prove the condition is reachable.

$x-w\pm \sqrt{1-xw}=0 \cap xw \le 1 \implies (x-w)^2=1-xw \iff $

$\\x^2-xw+w^2-1=0 \\ \tag 1\\x=\dfrac{w \pm \sqrt{4-3w^2}{}}{2}$

so there is infinity solution because from (1), we always have $0= x^2+w^2-xw-1 \ge xw-1 \iff xw \le 1$. details of $x-w$ curve  see picture below:

[image]

if you want integer ,there are 4 pairs for $x,w$

Comment: To simplify, $f(x,y,z,w)=2+\left((x-w)+\frac{1}{2}(y-z)\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}(y+z)^2$ for all $x,y,z,w\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $xw=yz+1$.  The minimum value of $f$ is $2$, which is attained iff there exists $t \in \left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right]$ such that $(x,y,z,w)=\left(\frac{+ \sqrt{4-3t^2}-t}{2},t,-t,\frac{+ \sqrt{4-3t^2}+t}{2}\right)$ or $(x,y,z,w)=\left(\frac{- \sqrt{4-3t^2}-t}{2},t,-t,\frac{- \sqrt{4-3t^2}+t}{2}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can build a quadratic form with a matrix.

Just put $${\bf x} = [x,y,z,w]^T$$ and then build a matrix $\bf A$ with the corresponding coefficients to the monomials in the right positions.

Then you can write the objective function like this ${\bf x}^T {\bf A x}$

Comment: How it can help? Don't forget about condition $xw=yz+1$.

Comment: Yes you are right, but maybe we can add this in matrix-vector form somehow.

Comment: Anyway the optimization problem is over integer numbers, so it is not trivial that the usual "calculus way" will provide the solution we want.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio,can you see this problem,I think you will interesting this problem

Comment: Yep you are all right. I misread the question.

Comment: I don't think we should be unduly critical of this approach; a key feature of learning math is trying things that might not work!                           (By Piet Hein) The road to wisdom? — Well, it's plain
and simple to express:
Err
and err
and err again
but less
and less
and less.

Comment: I would not have written this if I read that it was supposed to be an integer problem with constraints, but it seems stupid to erase now that we got some good comments to it anyways.